# There is a similar function json_merge_patch() in Postgres as in Oracle

Tags: postgresql, jsonb

My endpoint, accepts client request HTTP method PATCH, a payload content type of JSON Merge Patch (RFC 7396).
https://www.rfc-editor.org/rfc/rfc7396

We used Oracle and it was very convenient to update json content in the database, used function  **json_merge_patch**()

```
UPDATE table_name SET po_document =
  json_mergepatch(po_document, json_by_rfc7396);
```

https://docs.oracle.com/en/database/oracle/oracle-database/19/adjsn/updating-json-document-json-merge-patch.html

I have not found a similar function in Postgres, `jsonb_set()` and operators `||` and `#-`, not convenient for deep patches of json content.

What's the PostgreSQL best practice for deep patching json content?

Example:

```
SELECT json_merge_patch(
   '{"root": {"k1": "v1", "k2": "v2"} }'::jsonb, -- source JSON
   '{"root": {"k1": "upd", "k2": null, "k3": "new"} }'::jsonb -- JSON patch (RFC 7396)
)
```

Output

```
{"root": {"k1": "upd","k3": "new"} }
```

Comment: So what exactly are you trying to achieve? `jsonb_set` is probably the closest you can get (don't really know what that Oracle function does). But without more details, this is really hard to answer. Please **[edit]** your question (by clicking on the [edit] link below it) and add some sample data and the expected output based on that data as [formatted text](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/a/251362). See [here](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/81852) for some tips on how to create nice looking text tables.

Answer (score 4):

Leaving my 2 cents for a more compact solution here, based on [this post](https://blog.bguiz.com/2017/json-merge-postgresql/):

```
CREATE OR REPLACE FUNCTION json_merge_patch("target" jsonb, "patch" jsonb) RETURNS jsonb AS $$
    BEGIN
        RETURN COALESCE(jsonb_object_agg(
            COALESCE("tkey", "pkey"),
            CASE
                WHEN "tval" ISNULL THEN "pval"
                WHEN "pval" ISNULL THEN "tval"
                WHEN jsonb_typeof("tval") != 'object' OR jsonb_typeof("pval") != 'object' THEN "pval"
                ELSE json_merge_patch("tval", "pval")
            END
        ), '{}'::jsonb)
          FROM jsonb_each("target") e1("tkey", "tval")
     FULL JOIN jsonb_each("patch") e2("pkey", "pval")
            ON "tkey" = "pkey"
         WHERE jsonb_typeof("pval") != 'null'
            OR "pval" ISNULL;
    END;
$$ LANGUAGE plpgsql;
```

As far as I'm concerned, it follows the [RFC 7396](https://www.rfc-editor.org/rfc/rfc7396).

Answer (score 3):

The spec is simple enough to follow with recursion.

```
create or replace function jsonb_merge_patch(v_basedoc jsonb, v_patch jsonb) 
returns jsonb as $$                                            
with recursive patchexpand as(                                                        
  select '{}'::text[] as jpath, v_patch as jobj, jsonb_typeof(v_patch) as jtype, 0 as lvl
  union all
  select p.jpath||o.key as jpath, p.jobj->o.key as jobj, jsonb_typeof(p.jobj->o.key) as jtype, p.lvl + 1 as lvl
    from patchexpand p
         cross join lateral jsonb_each(case when p.jtype = 'object' then p.jobj else '{}'::jsonb end) as o(key, value)
), pathnum as (
  select *, row_number() over (order by lvl, jpath) as rn
    from patchexpand
), apply as (
  select case                          
           when jsonb_typeof(v_basedoc) = 'object' then v_basedoc 
           else '{}'::jsonb
         end as basedoc, 
         p.rn
    from pathnum p
   where p.rn = 1
  union all                                                                          
  select case
           when p.jtype = 'object' then a.basedoc
           when p.jtype = 'null' then a.basedoc #- p.jpath
           else jsonb_set(a.basedoc, p.jpath, p.jobj)
         end as basedoc,                                                                                              
         p.rn
    from apply a                                         
         join pathnum p
           on p.rn = a.rn + 1
)                       
select case 
         when jsonb_typeof(v_patch) != 'object' then v_patch 
         else basedoc 
       end
  from apply 
 order by rn desc 
 limit 1;                                                 
$$                                                   
language sql;
```

Testing with the example in the RFC:

```
select jsonb_pretty(jsonb_merge_patch('{
     "title": "Goodbye!",
     "author" : {
       "givenName" : "John",
       "familyName" : "Doe"
     },
     "tags":[ "example", "sample" ],
     "content": "This will be unchanged"
   }'::jsonb,
'{
     "title": "Hello!",
     "phoneNumber": "+01-123-456-7890",
     "author": {
       "familyName": null
     },
     "tags": [ "example" ]
   }'::jsonb));

               jsonb_pretty               
------------------------------------------
 {                                       +
     "tags": [                           +
         "example"                       +
     ],                                  +
     "title": "Hello!",                  +
     "author": {                         +
         "givenName": "John"             +
     },                                  +
     "content": "This will be unchanged",+
     "phoneNumber": "+01-123-456-7890"   +
 }
(1 row)
```

Testing with the example in your question:

```
SELECT jsonb_merge_patch(
   '{"root": {"k1": "v1", "k2": "v2"} }'::jsonb, -- source JSON
   '{"root": {"k1": "upd", "k2": null, "k3": "new"} }'::jsonb -- JSON patch (RFC 7396)
);

          jsonb_merge_patch           
--------------------------------------
 {"root": {"k1": "upd", "k3": "new"}}
(1 row)
```

Comment: The snippet works for most examples. What I just spottet is that it is not possible to add a nested json doc with an update. E.g. original '{"foo": "bar"}' and update with '{"foo": "bar", {"foo2": "bar2"}}'. The nested json is just not considered.

Comment: @Janukowitsch  Your example is not clear. That is not valid JSON.

Comment: Oh yes. You are right. I actually implemented the solution based on the tests from the example 3 from the [rfc](https://tools.ietf.org/html/rfc7386). During testing I realized there was a missing case and I just wanted to share here as well. The missing test case is: ` '{"foo": "bar"}' and update with '{"foo": "bar", "added-key": {"foo2": "bar2"}}'`. Actually, I decided to do the patch in the application and just select the respective row with for update, so I do not have a fix for the above. Of course this solution might not be optimal for everyone.